# Difference between datetime object returns only days

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two datetime objects but it only returns the difference between days and not between hours/minutes/seconds.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv(r'recorridos-realizados-2020.csv')

df.head(2)
Id_start    start_date          end_date                Id_end      ID_cyclist
75          2020-09-14 11:52:21 2020-09-14 11:58:10     186.0       155721
210         2020-09-14 11:51:41 2020-09-14 11:53:06     210.0       191320

df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['timelapse'] = df['end_date'] - df['start_date']

df['timelapse'].head()
0        0 days
1        0 days
```

The result should be:
0 days, 00:05:49
0 days, 00:01:25

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does `df['timelapse'].dt.total_seconds()` give you the correct values? p.s. ISO-format is parsed correctly by `pd.to_datetime`, you don't have to provide a format.

Comment: df['timelapse'].dt.total_seconds() gives me 0.0 for every row. Thanks for the advise about pd.to_datetime.

Comment: Your code works for me. I'm getting the seconds as well:
`0   0 days 00:05:49
1   0 days 00:01:25
`
What version of python and pandas are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [pandas time deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html).

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime('2020-09-14 11:52:21')
d2 = pd.to_datetime('2020-09-14 11:58:10')
delta = (d2-d1)

print('seconds: ', delta.seconds)
```